# implicit declaration of function 'gets' is invalid in C99

Tags: c

Why am I getting this error?

```
implicit declaration of function 'gets' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct myStruct
{
    char name[20];
    char tel[20];
}contact;

int main(void)
{
    contact *mycont[3];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        mycont[i] = (contact*)malloc(sizeof(contact));
        printf("Enter Name Of The Contact No.%d\n",i+1);
        gets(mycont[i]->name);
        printf("Enter The Contact Telephone Number\n");
        gets(mycont[i]->tel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `gets` is not a part of `c99` standard and should not be used. So it is excluded from the standard libraries.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The `gets` standard function is perfectly valid part of C99 standard. It has become obsolescent (deprecated) in C99 and it was removed in C11.

Comment: Really? I guess I've confused the standards. Sorry then.

Comment: @EugeneSh: Precisely, deprecation of `gets` was added in C99 TC3 (see [N1235](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1235.pdf)).

Comment: The message "implicit declaration of function 'gets' is invalid" suggests there is no function prototype in `stdio.h` (and an implicit declaration assumes `int` argument).

Comment: Perhaps the code is compiled with a flag that disables declarations of deprecated functions.

Comment: use `scanf` instead. using `gets` is dangerous.

Comment: Function `gets()` is deprecated. You are discouraged from using it because it is considered _insecure_.  What does it mean? In your program you pass it just a name of a _receiver array_, and it is impossible to know how long the input will be. If your user bears in mind that (s)he shouldn't write names longer than 20 characters, it's OK. However, if (s)he goes past that limit, so will `gets()`: **it will continue writing past the array boundary into memory it doesn't own**.

Comment: in C, when calling any of the memory allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc),  1)  do not cast the returned value.  The returned value has type `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain. 2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: strongly suggest using: `fgets()`  rather than `gets()`  as `fgets()` has a max length parameter, so does not allow input buffer overruns like `gets()` does.

Comment: See [Why `gets()` is so dangerous it should never be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used).  That doesn't explain why it was not declared when you have `<stdio.h>` included.  It should be, especially under C99 rules — it was a part of the C99 standard as of 1999, and was not deprecated until later, and was only removed from the standard in C11.  To understand what was happening, we'd probably need more information about the platform you're using (o/s, version, C compiler, version, command line used to compile).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is implicit declaration of gets() not allowed in C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256131/why-is-implicit-declaration-of-gets-not-allowed-in-c99)

Answer (score 3):

It's a safe bet that, even though the error message *mentions* `C99`, you are in fact using a compiler following a *later* standard, one in which `gets` was *removed* rather than just deprecated.

For example, when I try to compile the following simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char buff[1000];
int main(void) {
    gets(buff);
    return 0;
}
```

with `clang` under Ubuntu 18.04:

```
clang -Werror --std=c11 -o qq qq.c
```

I get that *same* error:

```
qq.c:4:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'gets' is invalid in C99
                 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

This is actually only *tangentially* related to the deprecation and removal of `gets` (in that it's no longer declared anywhere). It's more to do with the fact you shouldn't be trying to use *any* function without an active declaration, as per `ISO C99 Foreword /5` (paraphrased):

> This second edition cancels and replaces C90, as amended and corrected by various other ISO gumpf. Major changes from the previous edition include:
>
> - ***remove implicit function declaration.***
> - lots of other stuff, irrelevant to this question.

You can see this if you replace `gets` with `xyzzy`, which results in the same error:

```
qq.c:4:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'xyzzy' is invalid in C99
                 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

In fact, if you actually try to use `gets` with the `C99` flags set, you'll get a totally *different* message (or none at all if your compiler implements C99 before they deprecated `gets` - that wasn't done until TC3):

```
qq.c:4:2: error: 'gets' is deprecated
                 [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```